# Stack list item elements horizontally with separators

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I stack these list item elements horizontally with separators in between them?

For example:

```
<UI Layer> | <Business Layer> | <Services Layer> | <Data Access Layer>
```

NOTE: 
I would like to use bootstrap to support this but it's not required.

```
<div>
    <ul type="square">
        <li>UI Layer</li>
        <ul type="disc">
            <li>WPF</li>
            <li>Windows 8</li>
            <li>Windows Phone 8</li>
            <li>AngularJS</li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Business Layer</li>
        <ul type="disc">
            <li>Entity Framework</li>
            <li>LINQ</li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Services Layer</li>
        <ul type="disc">
            <li>WCF</li>
            <li>WebAPI</li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Data Access Layer</li>
        <ul type="disc">
            <li>SQL Server</li>
            <li>SQLite</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test Automation</li>
        <ul type="disc">
            <li>Unit Test</li>
            <li>Integration Test</li>
            <li>Coded UI</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "display: inline" on the li elements to force them to display horizontally. As far as the vertical separators, I would recommend either a border-right on the appropriate li's or an :after pseudo element with the vertical pipe character as the content.

```
li {
  display: inline;
}

li:after {
  width: 10px;
  content: "|";
}
```

Something along these lines should get you started. 
Do a "display: none" on the last li:after pseudo element.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element `::before` or `::after` and remove on the first or last child to achieve this,

css :

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
}

ul > li:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: " | ";
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/z7Btd/1/**

Comment: Thank you. But this is not creating the structure I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Bootstrap grid system (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to achieve the horizontal separation.

By using CSS you could achieve the separation you requested. Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="right-border col-md-4">
        <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet boudin andouille drumstick.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-border col-md-4">
        <p>Brisket short ribs tongue filet mignon, pork capicola chuck.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Meatball tri-tip chicken ham hock short loin turducken spare ribs. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in addition to the Bootstrap CSS you could add something like:

```
.right-border {
   border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error saying that I cannot use ul elements within div elements.

Comment: What editor are you using? You should be able to use a <ul> inside a <div>. According to http://validator.w3.org/ it's perfectly valid (although i know w3 not always tells the truth). If you post your code i'll look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My code was already posted. I am using VS2013.

Comment: Are you shure VS2013 said <ul> was not ok inside a <div>? Because in your code above you're using <ul> inside an <ul>, which is not supported. Consider using <h3> or something else as element for the headline and you should have no problem. If you want to wrap a <ul> inside a <ul> you first have to put it in a <li>. Example: <ul>
            <li>Business</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Entity Framework</li>
                    <li>Entity Framework</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>